Why doesn't HorizontalPodAutoscaler have a generation attribute in its metadata?
Context (why I'm asking)
I'm writing a kubernetes controller that issues patches on certain kinds of kubernetes resources under certain conditions. In order to know when it should take action, my controller watches for changes to relevant state, which includes changes to the specs of the kubernetes resources it manages. I can set a ResourceVersionChangedPredicate on the watch for any kind of resource, which will guarantee that the controller is notified of changes, even if the resource doesn't adhere to the "spec/status" paradigm. However, for the resource kinds that do follow the spec/status paradigm, I can do better, by setting a GenerationChangedPredicate and perhaps an AnnotationChangedPredicate and/or LabelChangedPredicate if appropriate, and thereby efficiently ignore changes to the resources' status (which my controller doesn't care about). For example, I do this for Deployment,  StatefulSet, and DaemonSet resources.
Question (what I'm asking)
With (autoscaling.v2.) HorizontalPodAutoscaler resources changes to their status are quite regular, but my controller is only interested in changes to their spec. I would really like to be able to set a GenerationChangedPredicate rather than a ResourceVersionChangedPredicate, but HorizontalPodAutoscaler resources apparently don't even have a generation attribute in their metadata. HorizontalPodAutoscaler clearly adheres to the spec/status paradigm, so I'm curious why kubernetes does not set its generation. Or perhaps there is a means for enabling it that I'm unaware of?
